# Doing an Image Search?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to perform an image search with google maps? For example, if I had a small section of a map, showing road configurations, but there were no labels to indicate street names or place names, is there a possible way to do an image search, similar to what you can do with regular google, to be able to identify that location? I have tried this with the regular google, and it does not work. Does anyone know of software or an app that has the ability to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it may be possible , But I do not think any software or app that is currently available a program would be need to be written that takes that small section of a map that you have and it would have to be a rather good quality image and preferaby in a raw Bitmap format  and then the small section of the map you provide would have to be overlaid over the main google map and then moved around the map... scanned  and each pixel compared frame by frame as the search picture is scanned across the bigger map and then a best-fit process would be utilized , and then when it finds a match it can then let you know just how closely it matches and what the confidence level it is that that the location found is actually correct , it would be best to narrow it down as much as possible as well, also a bit of artificial intelligence might be very useful here too, a face recognition A.I. program could be modified to complete that task. but as far as I know none of that exists in a single readily available app or program , maybe someday someone would create such a program? it is possible.